# Create a strikethrough in wxpython listctrl

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl, strikethrough

I am using a wx.listctrl inside a wxpython GUI.  I have a list that updates when I click a button.  Currently when I select an item and click the button, I do the following:

```
item = self.my_list.GetItem(row_in_list)
self.my_list.SetItemTextColour(row_in_list,'red')
```

In addition to turning the font red, I would like to "cross it out" or "strikethrough".  I have found `wx.FFont(8, wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS, face='Tahoma', flags = wx.FONTFLAG_STRIKETHROUGH)` but this does not seem to work.  Any one have ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: you will probably need something like http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/ultimatelistctrl_module.html#ultimatelistctrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, strike-throughs are not supported in the ListCtrl widget itself. You would have to create some kind of custom widget or switch to using the aforementioned UltimateListCtrl, which is a very flexible pure Python widget. You can see it in action in the wxPython demo package or read about in the following links:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.html
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/02/wxpython-an-intro-to-the-ultimatelistctrl/

Comment: That's upsetting I can't do it in ListCtrl.  Oh well -- I will look into switching to Ulimate Lists.  Thanks!